# How to change the color of the header when scrolling down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, header

The site has several sections. The first one with a picture, on it header should be transparent. The following blocks are colored and on them the header must take the color of the block. How can I achieve this?

I wrote code to change the header from transparent to the color of the second block, but I think there is a better solution than writing this for each block, but I can't find it.

```js
$(function() {
  let header = $('.header'),
    intro = $('.intro');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > intro.outerHeight()) {
      header.addClass('header_filled');
    } else {
      header.removeClass('header_filled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Animations */


/* Container */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_filled {
  background-color: #3ebb46;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  transition: .2s ease-in;
}


/* Intro */

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../img/intro.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.intro__inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.intro__title {
  font-size: 72px;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navigation */

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0d7711;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* About */

.about {
  background-color: #3ebb46;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 60px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.about__title {
  background-color: #61c467;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.about__text {
  text-align: justify;
}

.about__link {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #6868d8;
  text-decoration: wavy;
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.about__link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3ebb46;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: .1s ease-in;
}


/* Servives */

.services {
  background-color: #48daae;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 60px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="header" id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner" id="header">
      <a href="#main">
        <div class="header__logo">CottageKarelia</div>
      </a>
      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#main">Главная</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#about">О компании</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#services">Услуги</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Отдых в Карелии</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Владельцам</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Оплата</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro" id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro__inner">
      <h1 class="intro__title">Гостевые дома и коттеджи Карелии</h1>
      <br>
      <h2 class="intro__subtitle">Простой выбор для Вашего отдыха!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="about" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="about__title">
      <h1>О деятельности компании</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="about__text">
      <p>
        Наш сайт является крупнейшим <a class="about__link" href="catalog.html">каталогом</a> гостевых домов и коттеджей в Карелии, на котором собрано более 1000 позиций. Здесь Вы сможете найти любой дом, соответствующий всем Вашим потребностям. Благодаря
        удобной форме поиска, Вы наиболее полно сможете охарактеризовать, что именно Вам необходимо, после чего, Вам будут представлены наиболее подходящие дома. Когда Вы определитесь с выбором дома, Вам будет предложено забронировать его, после чего
        и начнется Ваш отдых! Кроме того, мы с радостью предлагаем гостям Карелии различные <a href="tours.html" class="about__link">туры</a>, созданные для абсолютно любой категории людей.
      </p>

      <p>
        Наши менеджеры свяжутся с Вами и узнают все Ваши пожелания, после чего они сформируют Вам тур: определят наиболее предпочтительные и удобные варианты проезда, сообщат о дополнительных возможностях на территории выбранного места или тура, посоветуют достопримечательности
        Карелии, которые можно будет посетить неподалеку от выбранного дома, предложат Вам трансфер с вокзала к гостевому дому или коттеджу и обратно. Иными словами, за Вас сделают все и обеспечат Вам лучший отдых на земле в райском уголке, по имени Карелия!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="services" id="services">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="services__title">
      <h1>Дополнительные услуги</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to determine wether the header block is above any of your blocks that change its color, you need to check if the header position + height "touches" the top edge of the element. After that you can simply apply the background color of the "touched" element to your header.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $header = $(".header");

    var header_position = $header.offset().top;
    var header_height = $header.outerHeight();

    $('.header-color').each(function(){

        var color_block_position = $(this).offset().top;

        if (header_position + header_height >= color_block_position) {
            $header.css({
                'background-color': $(this).css('background-color')
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #CECECE;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.header-color {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.transparent-background {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.yellowgreen-background {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.orangered-background {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.blue-background {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  HEADER
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="header-color transparent-background">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div class="header-color yellowgreen-background">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>

<div class="header-color orangered-background" >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>

<div class="header-color blue-background">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```